# PostgreSQL Trigger Function Syntax after `RETURNS TRIGGER AS`

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

So I saw this example in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql-trigger.html):

```
CREATE TABLE emp (
    empname text,
    salary integer,
    last_date timestamp,
    last_user text
);

CREATE FUNCTION emp_stamp() RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$
    BEGIN
        -- Check that empname and salary are given
        IF NEW.empname IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'empname cannot be null';
        END IF;
        IF NEW.salary IS NULL THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have null salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Who works for us when they must pay for it?
        IF NEW.salary < 0 THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION '% cannot have a negative salary', NEW.empname;
        END IF;

        -- Remember who changed the payroll when
        NEW.last_date := current_timestamp;
        NEW.last_user := current_user;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$emp_stamp$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER emp_stamp BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE emp_stamp();
```

where `RETURNS trigger AS $emp_stamp$` use the same name of the trigger. But in another example it was left empty `$$`.

What's the use of the name between the two `$`s?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

Comment: After reading the documentation and the linked post, I'm still confused: when is the tag in the double dollar sign used?  - My current guess is that tag captures the returned value of the function which can be used to substitute text later on.

Comment: @Jasper_Li: I added another original to clarify how dollar-quoting works - not like your current guess.

Comment: OK. So in an example of `$tag$blablabal$tag$`, the tag is just for clarification